# Have to pass input from first python file to second python file and second python file function should be called inside first python file

Tags: python

There are two python files namely script_a.py and script_b.py
I have to pass input from script_a.py to script_b.py function and that script_b.py function should be called inside script_a.py

script_a.py

```
from script_b import maximum
input1=5
input2=6
def script_a(input1,input2):
    input1,input2=input2,input1
    return input1,input2
print(script_a(input1,input2))
maximum(input1,input2)
```

script_b.py

```
import script_a

def maximum(a, b):
    if a >= b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
a = script_a.input1
b = script_a.input2
print(maximum)
```

when I execute script_a.py  I have to get answer for maximum function also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution to stop seeing the answer for the maximum function when running script_a.py would be to remove the last line of script_a.py - `maximum(input1, input2)`.

However, you should try to make your scripts as isolated as possible when using them for function or class definitions, in order to allow for efficient reuse. script_a.py and script_b.py should just provide function definitions. You could then have a main.py file which you will actually run. This will import then necessary function from the scripts and use them. For example:

script_a.py

```
def script_a(input1,input2):
    input1,input2=input2,input1
    return input1,input2
```

script_b.py

```
def maximum(a, b):
    if a >= b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

main.py

```
from script_a import script_a
from script_b import maximum

def run_script_a(input1, input2):
    print(script_a(input1, input2))

def run_script_b(input1, input2):
    print(script_b(input1, input2))

def main():
    input1 = 5
    input2 = 6

    run_script_a(input1, input2)
    #run_script_b(input1, input2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can uncomment the script that you want to run in the main function. This example is a bit verbose for such a simple program but if more efficient for code reuse in larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `def maximum(a, b)` in script_b file you are not using the imported script_a.input1 and script_a.input2. You are just declaring a function with parameters named a and b.

When you call maximum function from anywhere it does not care about a and b variables declared outside and above of function definition. They are out of scope.